# Ms-access query sql : Pick out one row for each client

Tags: jquery, sql, ms-access

I Have a table named purchases, which is listing clients and dates of purchases. I want to make a query that would give me, for EACH client, the most recent date of purchase. The thing is, for each client, i want to see the most recent date AND the rest of the informations linked to the purchase.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from purchases as p
where p.purchasedate = (select max(p2.purchasedate)
                        from purchases as p2
                        where p2.client = p.client
                       );
```

In your data, you appear to have a unique id.  That also suggest:

```
select p.*
from purchases as p
where p.id = (select top 1 p2.id
              from purchases as p2
              where p2.client = p.client
              order by p2.purchasedate desc
             );
```

Comment: Hi, i have done this but this gives me multiple lines of record for one client. I just want the most recent date for each client

Comment: @Acces124 . . . This gives only the most recent record for each client.  If you get duplicates, that is because you have duplicate most recent dates for a particular client.

Comment: @Acces124 . . . Assuming your table has a primary key (which I assume `id` is), then you can guarantee one row per client as in the edited version.